# Joining ComboBox Selection with TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a `DataTable` filled with rows of data, there are only two columns. The first column (item) is displayed in a combobox, and the second column (description), I want displayed in a textbox, since it is a string of text.

How can I write the code such that depending on the selection in the combobox, the respective description is displayed in the textbox?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: @JuniorJohn Funny story actually, I just figured it out.

Comment: Yes it should be very simple, i needed your code to show you how to implement it.

Comment: @JuniorJohn Thank you for the quick reply though:)

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DescriptionTextBox.Text = dt.Rows[ComboBox.SelectedIndex][1].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The SelectedIndex array can have no elements when this event is called. You might consider checking whether the ComboBox has any elements selected prior to taking any specific index.